# On radiobutton select value show only not all values in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This has definitely been covered before and im sure it will again but none of the examples ive found are helping me.

I have 4 radiobuttons and when r1 radiobutton is selected i want to display only Item1 that is otherwise hidden.

When r2 radiobutton is selected i want to display only Item1 Item2 and Item3 that is otherwise hidden.

When r3 radiobutton is selected i want to display only Item2 and Item3 and Item4 that is otherwise hidden.

**main.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div id='frm' class="w50">
                <form action="" method="post" >
                    <div>
                        <h1><u>Test</u></h1>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo isset($errors['DB']) ? $errors['DB'] : '';?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Date:</label>
                        <input id="date" type="date" name="date" <?php if(!empty($errors)) echo "value='" . $_POST["date"] . "'";?> />
                        <br><span class="error"><?php echo isset($errors['date']) ? $errors['date'] : '';?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Room:</label><br>
                        <input id="r1" type="radio" name="room" value="r1" <?php if(!empty($errors) && $_POST["room"] == 'r1') echo "checked='checked'";?> /> <label for="r1">rm1</label>
                        <input id="r2" type="radio" name="room" value="r2" <?php if(!empty($errors) && $_POST["room"] == 'r2') echo "checked='checked'";?> /> <label for="r2">rm2</label>
                        <input id="r3" type="radio" name="room" value="r3" <?php if(!empty($errors) && $_POST["room"] == 'r3') echo "checked='checked'";?> /> <label for="r3">rm3</label>
                        <input id="r4" type="radio" name="room" value="14a" <?php if(!empty($errors) && $_POST["room"] == 'r4') echo "checked='checked'";?> /> <label for="r4">rm4</label>
                        <br>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo isset($errors['room']) ? $errors['room'] : '';?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select id="tablnk" name="tab">
                            <option value="" data-tab="0">Choose...</option>
                            <option value="Item1" data-tab="1">Item1</option>
                            <option value="Item2" data-tab="2">Item2</option>
                            <option value="Item3" data-tab="3">Item3</option>
                            <option value="Item4" data-tab="4">Item4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab_content">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content_block">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="ch[]" value="val1" data-ch="1"><label for="ch1">val1</label><br>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="ch[]" value="val2" data-ch="2"><label for="ch2">val2</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="ch[]" value="val3" data-ch="3"><label for="ch3">val3</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch4" name="ch[]" value="val4" data-ch="4"><label for="ch4">val4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content_block">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch5" name="ch[]" value="val1" data-ch="5"><label for="ch5">val1</label><br>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch6" name="ch[]" value="val2" data-ch="6"><label for="ch6">val2</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch7" name="ch[]" value="val3" data-ch="7"><label for="ch7">val3</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch8" name="ch[]" value="val4" data-ch="8"><label for="ch8">val4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content_block">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch9" name="ch[]" value="val1" data-ch="9"><label for="ch9">val1</label><br>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch10" name="ch[]" value="val2" data-ch="10"><label for="ch10">val2</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch11" name="ch[]" value="val3" data-ch="11"><label for="ch11">val3</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch12" name="ch[]" value="val4" data-ch="12"><label for="ch12">val4</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script.js"></script>
                </body>
        </html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function(){

// tabs
    
    $('#tablnk').on('change', function (e) {
        let key = $('#tablnk option:selected').data('tab');
        
        $('.tab_content').fadeOut(400, function(){
            $('.tab_content_block').hide(100, function(){
                $('.tab_content_block input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                $('.tab_content_block input:checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#tab'+key).show();
            });
        }).fadeIn();
    });
     
    

    
});
```

Comment: So what’s the problem here? The unhiding part or the event firing part? You didn’t even ask any question till now. “I want to” is not a question. Also please provide the codes you have tried till now.

Comment: The JS code you posted doesn't have anything to do with the radio buttons.

Comment: Just add event handlers for `$("#r1").click()`, `$("#r2").click()`, etc.